# MSAccess VBA code error: Run-time error '424' object required

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm getting a run time error '424 on the below Access VBA code:

```
Private Sub btnDetailRpt_Click()

Dim strReportName As String

Dim strWhere As String

Dim strAging As String

Dim TheDate As Date

strReportName = "rptIncidentDetail"

strWhere = "1 = 1 "

strAging = DateDiff("d", Now, TheDate)

TheDate = Format([tblIncident]![CREATED_DT], "short date") ***This where error is***

If Not IsNull(Me.txtAging1) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " and strAging > " & Me.txtAging1 & " "

End If

Debug.Print strWhere

DoCmd.OpenReport strReportName, acViewReport, , strWhere

End Sub
```

I've created a form for our user to filter by aging and it doesn't seem to recognize the field.  Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't pull data directly from table like that. Is there a textbox on form bound to CREATED_DT? Or use DLookup() domain aggregate function. Which record does value need to be pulled from?

Comment: Also, WHERE clause is constructed incorrectly. Makes no sense to embed variable within quote marks. Instead should be field name that filter should be applied to `" and fieldname > " & strAging`. Also, can't calculate strAging before TheDate is populated.

Comment: Why declare string variable for numeric value - strAging ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you are doing, but try these modifications:

```vb
strWhere = "1 = 1 "

If Not IsNull(Me.txtAging1) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " and DateDiff('d', [CREATED_DT], Now()) > " & Str(Me.txtAging1) & ""
End If
```

Comment: I've created a form for the users to run a report based on Aging from the 'Created_dt'.  Created_dt is a field from the tblIncident table.  So basically I'm calculating an aging from the 'created_dt' and today's date (DateDiff("d", TheDate, Now). the user will type i.e.10 to generate a report that is greater than 10 days(for example).  Where the types the number of days is an unbound box title txtAging1,  Once this works, i'll adjusted to say i.e. give me anything from 10 to  20 days, etc.  But i'm trying the first part...

Comment: But where are data for the report pulled from?

Comment: Directly from the table, tblIncident

Comment: Dim strReportName As String
Dim TheDate As Date
Dim strAging As Long
Dim strWhere As String
strReportName = "rptDGIncDetail"
TheDate = [tbldgincident]![CREATED_DT]
strAging = DateDiff("d", Now, TheDate)
strWhere = "1 = 1 "
If Not IsNull(Me.txtAging1) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " and strAging > " & Me.txtAging1 & " "

End If

Debug.Print strWhere

DoCmd.OpenReport strReportName, acViewReport, , strWhere

End Sub
Change the code to the above format and now I'm getting an error '2465' can't find field '|1' referred to in your expression.

Comment: OK. See simplified answer, please.